# Apache poi page breaks

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, page-break

I need to create a simple word document for printing from a java program. It is necessary to have the output printed on separate pages. I'm using the following code:

```js
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("TITLE");
run.addCarriageReturn();
run.setText("some text and stuff here");
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
run.setText("more text");
run.addCarriageReturn();
run.setText("one more line");
```

Trouble is, anything I try to insert after this page break appears on its own on a page (the last two lines of text in the above example will appear on different pages). It's as if there is now an 'auto-page-break' after every statement.
I've tried using new run, or new paragraph, but the result is always the same. Any ideas? Starting to get very frustrated here....

Comment: You use BreakType.PAGE which, acoording to the documentation: Specifies that the current break shall restart itself on the next page of the document when the document is displayed in page view.

Comment: That's what I have done. But it seems to have a knock on effect and puts everything after it onto separate pages...

Answer (score 14):

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
...
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
paragraph.setPageBreak(true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Have found an answer - not sure it's the best way.
It's necessary to add a carriage return after the last line of the page, or it too moves to the next page.
Then add Break (WORD_WRAPPING), and start a new run for the next page.
(The only problem with this solution is it leaves a blank line at the top of each new page!)

```js
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("TITLE");
run.addCarriageReturn();
run.setText("some text and stuff here");
run.addCarriageReturn();                 //separate previous text from break
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
run.addBreak(BreakType.WORD_WRAPPING);   //cancels effect of page break
WXPFRun run2 = paragraph.createRun();    //create new run
run2.setText("more text");
run2.addCarriageReturn();
run2.setText("one more line");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("Text");
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
XWPFRun run2 = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("Another text");
```