# How to set Page Breaks View Mode for .xls using hssfwork book ApachePOI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating an .xls excel file using apache poi. I need to set the Page Breaks View by default. But I did look at a related question on .xlsx file . I didn't find anything "how to set Page Breaks View Mode" to using HSSF of ApachePOI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW9rK.png)

Comment: have you tried google? statckoverflow have many answers related to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539760/apache-poi-page-breaks

Comment: Do you mean print areas? You can get or set the print areas using HSSFPrintSetup as shown here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPrintSetup.html for example `PrintSetup ps = sheet.getPrintSetup(); ps.setFitHeight(pageCount);`

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking, but this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861001/set-page-view-mode-in-excel-file-using-apache-poi

Comment: I try stackoverflow.com/questions/7861001/…  but It didn't work.

Comment: @sorifiend i think it don't print areas. It is View modes for Excel. Please see my attachment

Comment: Ok, so CTSheetView is actually part of the openxmlformats library, with the following import `import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;` and does not appear to be exposed from within Apache POI, however, once you have added this library you should then be able to interact with CTSheetView similar to how it is done within Apache POI: https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/a60f552c5908dfaad31cfc0db6ef82690dcd5b96/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java#L3503 I will leave the rest with you, that is enough digging for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary `BIFF` file system of `*.xls` and the `Office Open XML` file system of `*.xlsx` are two totally different file systems. You can't mix them. In `apache poi` `HSSF` ist for the one and `XSSF` for the other. The high level classes of `apache poi` try providing methods for both the file systems. This gets done using interfaces in `SS`. But outside the  high level classes one needs strictly differentiate the both file systems.

Setting page break preview for a sheet is not provided by the high level classes up to now. So we need the underlyinf low lewel classes. For `XSSF` this are the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*` classes, which are the `XML` representation of the `XSSF` internals.  But for `HSSF` this are the `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.*` classes, which are the binary representation of the `HSSF` internals.

Setting page break preview for a sheet could be done like so for both the file systems:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.WindowTwoRecord;

public class ExcelPageBreakPreview {
  
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelTemplate.xlsx")); String filePath = "./ExcelInPageBreakPreview.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelTemplate.xls")); String filePath = "./ExcelInPageBreakPreview.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  //set sheet in PageBreakPreview
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   XSSFSheet xssfSheet= (XSSFSheet)sheet;   
   xssfSheet.lockSelectLockedCells(true);
   xssfSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0).setView(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STSheetViewType.PAGE_BREAK_PREVIEW);   
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   HSSFSheet hssfSheet= (HSSFSheet)sheet; 
   InternalSheet internalSheet = hssfSheet.getSheet(); 
   WindowTwoRecord record = internalSheet.getWindowTwo();
   record.setSavedInPageBreakPreview(true);
  }

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Previous `apache poi` versions might not have `InternalSheet HSSFSheet.getSheet` public. Then one needs using reflection to get the `InternalSheet`:

```
   //InternalSheet internalSheet = hssfSheet.getSheet(); 
   java.lang.reflect.Field _sheet = HSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredField("_sheet");
   _sheet.setAccessible(true); 
   InternalSheet internalSheet = (InternalSheet)_sheet.get(hssfSheet);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: when i checked HSSFSheet.class then method getSheet() is lock in package . I'm using Apache POI version 3.17. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Huy Nguyễn Ngọc: My examples always using the current `apache poi` version. Simply do not using ancient versions. They are not more supported by `apache poi`.  In `apache poi 3.17` one needs using reflection to get the `InternalSheet`. See my supplement in the answer.

Comment: thank, It's working for me